# Avoid UIVIew size constraints

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout, interface-builder

I am making a score marker for a game. As the score grows I want the marker to grow so it can accommodate the extra digits that are being added. I want the resizing to be smooth and also animate the new score that is displayed. At first I was using a `UILabel` but later found out I can't animate the background and the text independently (because they are in the same layer).

I decided to subclass `UIView` and add a `CATextLayer` as a sub layer so I can now animate the background (the `UIView` layer) and the text (the `CATextLayer` sub layer) independently.

It works great except for one thing, I placed the marker at the center bottom of of the screen like this:[image]

the problem is that I get an error saying I should add constraints for x and y position or width and height. Since I want the view to be able to grow I can't add size constraints, and since it's is relative I can't add x or y constraints. Using an inequality constraint is useless as the error still occurs.

I know this isn't a problem using `ILabel`, `UIButton` or some other subclass of UIView. I guess I could subclass UILabel instead and just leave the text empty to achieve the same effect plus I won't have to worry about those constraints, but that feels somewhat wrong. Besides `UILabel` already is a subclass of UIView so I guess there probably is an option to avoid having to set size constraints.

Is there something I can do to still subclass UIView or should I just subclass UILabel or something like that and get it for free.

Answer (score 0):

Try **CONTENT HUGGING PRIORITY**. or **CONTENT COMPRESSION RESISTANCE PRIORITY**. Here is a tutorial to understand about them clearly, if you are not familiar with them.
[Hugging priority Vs Compression resistence](https://krakendev.io/blog/autolayout-magic-like-harry-potter-but-real)

There is another option to try. If getting auto layout errors is the only problem you are facing, except everything is fine, you can use **Place holder constraints**.